# Unable to login into typo3 backend using chrome

Tags: typo3-8.x, typo3-9.x

I have weird problem in fresh TYPO3 9.5 and 8.7 installations.

Trying to login into the backend

- login with **correct username/password**, a few secs of load indicator and then the login form is shown again. No login possible.
- login with **invalid username/password**, as expected "Your login attempt did not succeed
  Make sure to spell your username and password correctly, including upper/lowercase characters."

There are other problems which are maybe related:

- Renaming a file in the File module seems to do nothing, the file itself is renamed. The new name is displayed only after a total refresh of the page.
- Deleting log entries. Clicking a log entry deletes it but the list is updated only on refresh
- other situations where changes are not reflected in the browser until the page is reloaded.

This happens on MacOS Catalina 10.15.2 / Chrome 79.0.3945.88?

At the same time Firefox seems to work.

Chrome seems to work normally everywhere else.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Found a solution:

Even creating a new news entry did not do anything. The browser console told me:

`Mixed Content: The page at 'https://bla.com' was loaded over HTTPS, but requested an insecure resource 'http://bla.com/something'. This request has been blocked; the content must be served over HTTPS.`

The site is reachable via https only.

The site was running behind a reverse proxy which proxied all https requests to the real server using http, because proxy-server traffic happens in a DMZ anyways.

TYPO3 seems generate some URLs based on the request url. And the browser complains at mixed (http) reqests that are handled via Javascript.

I modified the proxy config to pass all https requests via https and all is fine.

Comment: there is a http-header (Strict-Transport-Security / HSTS) which tells the browser to use a domain always with `https`. maybe your chrome browser did not get it, while other browsers already switched protocol automatically. you might change your server config to provide this header with a meaningful value (>1 year)

Comment: HSTS is implemented, but the problem really was that the reverse proxy routed incoming https to the web server via http. TYPO3 seems to create the URLs for Javascript calls according to the incoming requests.

Answer (score 0):

I had the same error after upgrade to v11. I lost hours to fix it, but finally I found this [German forum](https://www.typo3forum.net/discussion/85364/login-ins-typo3-backend-funktioniert-nach-update-auf-typo3-11-nicht-mehr), and solution was length of **ses_id** field in table **be_sessions**. In my case it was 32, and with 190 it works.

> "Ich habe die funktionierende Neuinstallation mit der nicht
> funktionierenden Update-Version verglichen. Das PHP-Script ist beim
> Lesen der Daten aus be_sessions abgebrochen. Das Feld ses_id war
> einmal 32 Zeichen lang und einmal 190. Nachdem ich das mit diesem Befehl
> geändert habe, ging der Login:
>
> ALTER TABLE be_sessions modify COLUMN ses_id VARCHAR(190) NOT NULL;"